# equivalent of network connection tracking parameters on windows

Tags: networking

On a Linux machine I can use "sysctl net" to see or change many network related parameters, such as max concurrent connections, tcp/udp timeout, etc. Are there any equivalent thing on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I believe you are after is:

```
netsh
```

Beyond that, the values under the following registry keys may offer you something but many of the netsh commands will set/get values from these keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{GUID}\
```

See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962453.aspx for more info.